# How to put custom Gradle plugins on an another projects build classpath?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have a published gradle plugin which looks something like this:

```
|__root
|     |
|     |
|     |__java
|     |    |__SomeJavaClass.java
|     |    |__SomeJavaClass2.java
|     |
|     |__kotlin
|          |__MyPluginClass.kts
|          |__MyTaskClass.kts
|          |__Utils.kts
```

I would like to include this plugin as a project in my multi project build instead of publishing it to a repo for easier developement.

This plugin has 3 Kotlin files Project A is using. MyPluginClass.kts has my own plugin class, MyTaskClass.kts has my own task class and Utils.kts contains only kotlin functions. The java classes are used in MyPlugin and MyTask.

It is being put on Project A's build.gradle.kts classpath as

```
classpath("com.my:custom.plugin:version")
```

A very simplified project structure I would like to achieve:

```
root
| 
|__Project A
|     |
|     |__build.gradle.kts
|     |__x.gradle.kts
|     |__y.gradle.kts
|     |__settings.gradle
|
|__Project build-logic
|     |
|     |__build.gradle.kts
|     |
|     |__java
|     |    |__SomeJavaClass.java
|     |    |__SomeJavaClass2.java
|     |
|     |__kotlin
|          |__MyPluginClass.gradle.kts
|          |__MyTaskClass.gradle.kts
|          |__Utils.gradle.kts
```

I'm trying to create plugins from those kotlin files and include them in my main build because i need them precompiled, but i cant seem to find a way to put them on Project A's classpath when build.gradle is running there. Is it even possible? what would be the proper solution?

I'm using gradle 7.3

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

Comment: @Jorn Tried it, didn't work. Screwed up the whole build. The main gradle script couldn't see scripts right next to it, tasks couldn't see the applied java plugin etc. Didn't have much time to investigate, could be because our build structure is a bit odd, the main gradle build files are not in the root project, but in an ear project.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you're defining the plugin you want to share, and how you're applying it, in the `build.gradle.kts` of both `Project A` and `Project build-logic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly figured out. I didn't create plugins from build-logic, left them as kotlin files. Since it is a separate gradle project, i can just build the project and point project A's classpath to the produced jar file like

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(files("path.to.the.jar"))
    }
}
```

this way i can access methods and the MyTask from Project A.

The other issue was that i wanted to apply MyPlugin like

```
plugins{
    id("my-plugin-name")
}
```

which wasnt working, i guess because it is a class. But now since i had the whole project jar on my build classpath, i can do this:

```
apply<my-plugin-name>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple, independent, Gradle projects using [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_builds). The same is also true for Gradle plugins.

Including a Gradle plugin from another directory is documented in the [Testing Gradle plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/testing_gradle_plugins.html#manual-tests) section.

So if you have a `shared-build-logic` project that provides a Gradle plugin with an ID `my.shared-build-logic`, and you want to use that in `project-a`.

```
my-projects/
├── shared-build-logic/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── settings.gradle.kts
└── project-a/
    ├── src/
    │   └── ...
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    └── settings.gradle.kts
```

Then you need to include `shared-build-logic` in your `project-a` Gradle settings file.

```kotlin
// my-projects/project-a/settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "project-a"

pluginManagement {
  includeBuild("../shared-build-logic")
}
```

Now, so long as `shared-build-logic` correctly provides a Gradle plugin, in `project-a` you can reference that plugin.

```kotlin
// my-projects/project-a/settings.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("my.shared-build-logic")
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried to apply the plugin, i don't think it puts the classes on the classpath. The build failed because it couldn't see functions from one of the plugins. Or am i dum and there should be a prefix or something?